# How to add a reference?

Tags: hyperref

The package

```
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
```

Doesn't work to create a colored reference on my note. The template I am using is this one

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,x11names,svgnames]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{vector}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,positioning,backgrounds}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,amscd,xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,lipsum,cancel}
\usepackage[ISBN=978-80-85955-35-7]{ean13isbn}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
bla bla bla...
\appendix
\cleardoublepage\part*{Appendix}
bla bla bla...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which reference? By default, bookmarks are not coloured, this needs the `bookmark` package, but even then, this need more setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `bookmark` package and `\bookmarksetup{color=...}` for coloured bookmarks. The settings are persistent until the next `\bookmarksetup` or an explicit `\bookmark` command.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany,x11names,svgnames]{memoir}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{verbatim} 
%\usepackage{vector}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{wallpaper}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,positioning,backgrounds}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,amscd,xspace}
%\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[ISBN=978-80-85955-35-7]{ean13isbn}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\bookmarksetup{color=blue,bold}
\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
bla bla bla...
\bookmarksetup{color=red,italic}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foobar}
\appendix
\cleardoublepage
\part*{Appendix}
bla bla bla...


\end{document}
```

[image]